# update custom post meta from front end form

Tags: php, wordpress

This is how i am getting custom post meta within query.

```
<?php 
        $collections = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'do_collection');
        if( !$collections || !$collections[0] )
            return;
            foreach ( $collections[0] as $collection ) :
            echo '<p>'.$collection['song-title'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$collection['song-category'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$collection['song-layrics'].'</p>';
        endforeach;
?>
```

Now i am trying to get custom post meta values from the form on frontend.
but when i submit form from frontend i get all meta fields with a first alphabet in admin area.

```
<?php 
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

    $new_post = array(
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',
    'post_type' =>  'do_songs'
    );
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    update_post_meta($pid, 'do_collection',  $_POST['song-title']);
    update_post_meta($pid, 'do_collection',  $_POST['song-category']);
    update_post_meta($pid, 'do_collection',  $_POST['song-layrics']);

    $link = get_permalink( $pid );
    wp_redirect( $link );
}
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
?>

<div class="form-wrap">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="song-title">Song Title:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" tabindex="35" name="song-title" id="song-title" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="song-category">Song Category:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" tabindex="35" name="song-category" id="song-category" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="song-layrics">Song Layrics:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" tabindex="35" name="song-layrics" id="song-layrics" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead

```
$collection = array();
$collection['song-title'] = $_POST['song-title'];
$collection['song-category'] = $_POST['song-category'];
$collection['song-lyrics'] = $_POST['song-lyrics'];

update_post_meta($pid, 'do_collection', $collection);
```

Is the meta 'do_collection' supposed to be a multi-dimensional array?
If not, you could update the way you retrieve the metadata:

```
$collection = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'do_collection', TRUE);

if( !$collection ) return;

echo '<p>'.$collection['song-title'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$collection['song-category'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$collection['song-layrics'].'</p>';
```

Comment: Be sure to escape your $_POST data. http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still the same problem after using your solution. if i write "TEST" in song-title field i'll get "T" in all fields.

Comment: Is the meta 'do_collection' supposed to be a multi-dimensional array?
If not, you could update the way you retrieve the metadata:

$collection = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'do_collection', TRUE);

if( !$collections ) return;

echo '<p>'.$collection['song-title'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$collection['song-category'].'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$collection['song-layrics'].'</p>';

Comment: Thanks man your answer is acceptable.
i did $collection[0]['song-title'] = $_POST['song-title']; and it fixed.